# Real-time Geolocation Tracking

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm using the [google maps javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY18-Q2-global-demandgen-paidsearchonnetworkhouseads-cs-maps_contactsal_saf&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_359194145412-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20~%20Google%20Maps%20Javascript%20API-KWID_43700045479855436-aud-581578347266:kwd-341556983684-userloc_9018884&utm_term=KW_%2Bmaps%20%2Bjavascript%20%2Bapi-ST_%2Bmaps%20%2Bjavascript%20%2Bapi&gclid=Cj0KCQjw84XtBRDWARIsAAU1aM00eMsPN1O89kbKfL2ppMmzbJF1rbGYUUObG2ZP4tPvfoRUlf_YCgsaAqxQEALw_wcB) to render a map. I'm using Python's Django v2 but the actual code for the API interaction and map creation is just Javascript.

The client has have a fleet of trucks and I'd like to suggest a new feature: tracking the trucks' real-time location on the map. If each of the trucks had an tablet I imagine I could somehow get near-real-time geolocation information from that device.

Question: Should I be trying to **send** geolocation info from the tablets *to the server* (if so how?) or should I be trying to **GET/retrieve** the geolocation *from the tablets* (if so how?)? Thinking of apps like Uber or Lyft what is the best practice/tried-and-true protocol to use with IOT & geolocation?

Comment: This link will give you all the background you need https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/745

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [GPS Tracker for Android](https://gpslogger.app/). It's open source and on the Google Play/Apps store for free. It has an option to POST to my server the geolocation of any Android device I set it up on.